# Drawing Tool in WebForm

Tags: webforms

Drupal 6 website.

I need to embed a drawing tool into a webform to allow a visitor to sketch a diagram and have it sent as an attachment to the email from the WebForm.

Been looking around but have not found a solution for Drupal 6.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://drupal.org/project/canvas_field for drupal 7, see demo here http://rbayliss.net/canvas-field-demo

Answer (score 1):

[Image Editor](https://drupal.org/project/imageeditor) will do that,

Drupal 6 version allows to edit Imagefield items and save them back either by replacing the original image or adding new Imagefield item. but I'm not sure it will integrate with webform, You need to test it.

See the [Demo Here](http://d6.andrewberezovsky.ru/node/1/edit)

> Bring image editing (draw, text, crop, scale, etc.) functionality into
>   your Drupal website! Edit/create any images online in the powerful and
>   feature-rich image editors and save resulted images back to your site!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [painter module](https://drupal.org/project/painter)

> The Painter provides dynamic image creation and manipulation
>   capabilities by allowing the definition of sequences of image IO,
>   manipulation and drawing operations that can be applied to fields
>   within content types and views, as well as to page elments such as the
>   logo, navigation, titles and buttons.